# oracle client 32bit is not working

Tags: dependencies

I am facing the following error when i try to run sqlplus or tnsping executables from the /bin dir

Error:

```
/opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4_32/bin $ sqlplus

sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries: libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Expected: ( sample from a different working host )

```
/oracle/software/oraClient/11.2.0.2_32/bin $ sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Tue Jan 23 16:49:16 2018
Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle. All rights reserved.

Enter user-name:
```

I have also searched for this libaio.so.1 file from the non-working host and i ended up in the following.

```
/opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4_32/bin $ find / -name "libaio.so.1" -type f 2> /dev/null

/opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4_32/lib/stubs/libaio.so.1    
/opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4/lib/stubs/libaio.so.1
```

I had the 64 bit previously installed but never really used it with my reporting application. As i wanted 32bit client, i have got it installed but still did not solve my purpose,

on troubleshooting, that's when i have realized the problem with the client itself.

how can i get my client working in this non-working host. ?

any ideas ?

Comment: Seems like the install is incorrect. Has this been built from source or installed with a package manager?

Answer (score 1):

Install the `libaio1` dependency. Using `apt`

```
sudo apt install libaio1
```

That should get you rolling.